# Подсчет количества сравнений и перестановок чисел при сортировке

Tags: python, функции, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

Приложу фрагмент своей программы в виде алгоритма сортировки пузырьковым методом по возрастанию и по спаданию чисел:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit


def bubble_sort(arr):
    len_arr = len(arr)
    for i in range(len_arr):
        for j in range(0, len_arr - 1 - i):
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]


def reversed_bubble_sort(arr):
    len_arr = len(arr)
    for i in range(len_arr):
        for j in range(0, len_arr - 1 - i):
            if arr[j] < arr[j + 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]


arr = np.empty(1000, dtype=int)
print(f'Non-sorted array: \n {arr}')

reverse_check = input('Choose the sort order: \n 1.Ascending \n 2.Descending \n')
if reverse_check == '1':
    bubble_sort(arr)
else:
    reversed_bubble_sort(arr)

bubble_sort(arr)
len_arr = len(arr)
print(f'Sorted array: \n {arr}')
t = timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000)
print(f"Program was executed by {t} seconds")
```

Каким образом здесь можно реализовать вывод подсчета количества сравнений чисел и их перестановок в функции сортировки в зависимости от того, какой порядок сортировки выбрал пользователь? Пытался играться с видимостью переменных, разными способами вывода результатов подсчетов, но все безрезультатно.
P.S знаю, что скорее всего ответ будет слишком простым и очевидным, но я только изучаю функции, а ответов на подобные вопросы в гугле найти не смог. Буду благодарен за любую помощь, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def bubble_sort(arr):
    num_comp = 0
    num_moves = 0
    len_arr = len(arr)
    for i in range(len_arr):
        for j in range(0, len_arr - 1 - i):
            num_comp += 1
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                num_moves += 1
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
    return num_comp, num_moves

num_comp, num_moves = bubble_sort(arr)
```

**Дополнение.**

[numpy.empty](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) не создаёт массив псевдослучайных чисел. Эта функция создаёт незаполненный массив заданного размера, в котором лежит мусор. Чтобы создать массив псевдослучайных чисел, пользуйтесь функцией [numpy.random.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
np.random.randint(low, high, size=n)
```

Comment: Для пузырьковой сортировки, кстати, количество сравнений зависит только от длины массива. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-total-number-of-comparisons-in-a-bubble-sort

Comment: А почему при запуске вашего кода у меня показывает, что количество перестановок равно нулю?

Comment: @nc_6d, потому что их 0. Что вы подаёте на вход?

Comment: Массив из псевдослучайных чисел

Comment: @nc_6d, покажите, как вы его создаёте

Comment: arr = np.empty(100, dtype=int)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106534/discussion-between-nc-6d-and--).